# How to return all values while iterating through list?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

public Details getDetails(String id) throws InvokerException {
    Details details = new Details();

```
try {

    URL url = new URL(BaseUrl, "/cxf/query/ask?id=" + id);
    LOGGER.trace("URL: {}", url);

    String xml = queryStore(url);
    LOGGER.trace("Query result: {}", xml);

    details = new Details();
    InputSrc source = new InputSrc(new StringReader(xml));
        ResultsContentHandler handler = new ResultsContentHandler();

    XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    reader.setContentHandler(handler);
    reader.parse(source);

    for (Hashtable<String,String> result : handler.getResultSet()) {
        String baseId = result.get("baseId");
        ArrayList<Details> list = getHistoryDetails(baseId );

        for(Details t : list) {
        details.setStatus(t.getStatus());
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new InvokerException(e);
}
return details;
```

}

What i want to achieve is to return the details for all items in the Arraylist. For example, I expect more than one status, but currently i'm getting just one status.

Details class

```
public class Details {
    private Core core;
    private String department;
    private GregorianCalendar timestampReceived;
    private GregorianCalendar timestampReported;
    private String status;
    private GregorianCalendar timestampStatus;
    private String explanation;

    public Details(){}

    public Details(Core core,
            String department, GregorianCalendar timestampReceived,
            GregorianCalendar timestampReported, String status,
            GregorianCalendar timestampStatus, String explanation) {
        super();
        this.core = core;
        this.department = department;
        this.timestampReceived = timestampReceived;
        this.timestampReported = timestampReported;
        this.status = status;
        this.timestampStatus = timestampStatus;
        this.explanation = explanation;
    }
    public Core getCore() {
        return core;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public GregorianCalendar getTimestampReceived() {
        return timestampReceived;
    }

    public GregorianCalendar getTimestampReported() {
        return timestampReported;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public GregorianCalendar getTimestampStatus() {
        return timestampStatus;
    }

    public String getExplanation() {
        return explanation;
    }

    public void setCore(Core core) {
        this.core = core;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public void setTimestampReceived(GregorianCalendar timestampReceived) {
        this.timestampReceived = timestampReceived;
    }

    public void setTimestampReported(GregorianCalendar timestampReported) {
        this.timestampReported = timestampReported;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setTimestampStatus(GregorianCalendar timestampStatus) {
        this.timestampStatus = timestampStatus;
    }

    public void setExplanation(String explanation) {
        this.explanation = explanation;
    }


}
```

Comment: Then you aren't populating your ArrayList the way you think you are. Change your expectations or investigate them. We're not going to do it for you.

Comment: Lot of people could say *return a `List<Detail>` instead*, *move the `Detail detail = new Details();` inside the loop*, and *fill your list with this new instance* but looks that you haven't tried anything on your own...

Comment: What is this `Details` class? How does it work? Show us some code!

Comment: @Code-Guru that's not relevant to solve the problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Certainly it is. If the Details class keeps a list of multiple items, then the OP is likely using it incorrectly. On the other hand, if Details is just a single item, then the OP needs to roll their own solution (most likely using a List of some kind).

Comment: @Code-Guru then let's wait for OP to edit its question and hope you're right and not me.

Comment: @Code-Guru The Details class keeps a list of multiple items.

Comment: @SykWitIt Please show the code from `Details` which is relevant to your question.

Comment: @Code-Guru I have just added the code from Details

Answer (score 1):

You can't return multiple values in just one call to a method, however what you should do is return an ArrayList:

```
public List<Details> getDetails(String id) throws InvokerException {
    List<Details> details = new ArrayList<Details>();

    try {

        URL url = new URL(BaseUrl, "/cxf/query/ask?id=" + id);
        LOGGER.trace("URL: {}", url);

        String xml = queryStore(url);
        LOGGER.trace("Query result: {}", xml);

        InputSrc source = new InputSrc(new StringReader(xml));
            ResultsContentHandler handler = new ResultsContentHandler();

        XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(handler);
        reader.parse(source);

        Details detail;
        for (Hashtable<String,String> result : handler.getResultSet()) {
            String baseId = result.get("baseId");
            ArrayList<Details> list = getHistoryDetails(baseId );

            for(Details t : list) {
            detail = new Details();
            detail.setStatus(t.getStatus());
            details.add(detail);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new InvokerException(e);
    }
    return details;
}
```

Comment: I don't undestand why to create a new `Detail` instance just to set the `status` attribute and then add it into the list. Why don't just add the whole `detail` object from `ArrayList<Details> list` into `details`?

Comment: I agree with you, but as is not my code I try to correct it as close as the one he gave us :), maybe he only wants the statuses and not all the info the object could carry.

Comment: Status is just one of the items the Details class have.

Comment: Then probably what you are looking for in return is an ArrayList<Status>.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a `List<Details>`, not just Details. So you are wanting to return the variable "list" in your code example.

Comment: If you analyse the whole code, you will see so many error that you should re edit this answer and provide a solution for all them.

Comment: It might get him going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ArrayList<Details>()` and add the details to it. Afterwards, return this list.

Code:

```
List<Details> detailsToReturn = new ArrayList<>();

for (Hashtable<String,String> result : handler.getResultSet()) {
            String baseId = result.get("baseId");
            ArrayList<Details> list = getHistoryDetails(baseId );

            for(Details t : list) {
                Details temp = new Details();
                temp.setStatus(t.getStatus();
                detailsToReturn.add(temp);
            }
        }

return detailsToReturn;
```

The code you provided is very unclear so if this isn't what you want, I suggest you clear it up for us.

Answer (score 0):

You only create *one* `Details` object (well two actually, but the first one is thrown away). If you want to keep every `Details` object you retrieve from the `ArrayList`, you need to create a new `Details` object each time you iterate the for loop. You should also add these to a new `List`.

Of course, you can save yourself a lot of work by simply appending each `ArrayList` that you get from `getHistoryDetails()` onto a new list.

Comment: Code-Guru can u give an example?